# Share module api among require js modules

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, architecture, requirejs, amd

Can you please give some clear way to share data and API from require.js AMD modules among them.

First time i used just an `publicData: {}` object in `Backbone.Router` but this was a bit messy.

After that i tried to create `Bridge` module something like this:

```
require(['underscore', 'backbone'], function (_, Backbone) {
  var Bridge = function Bridge () {};
  _.extend(Bridge.prototype, Backbone.Events, {
    set: function () {/*some code*/},
    get: function () {/*some code*/},
    has: function () {/*some code*/},
    remove: function () {/*some code*/},
  });
  return new Bridge();
});
```

And it mostly works. Then i add some api to `Bridge` in root `App` and include it somewhere in a nested views e.t.c But i'm not sure if it messes my dependency-tree. Cause i want to keep App as simple and straightforward as i can.
Now i have deps something like this

```
           |->Collection->Model
App->Module|->SingleModel
           |->View->Nested View
```

And now exacly `Module` provide API wich required for me somewhere aroud `Nested View` to inject selectable data from another Modules.
If you have better solution please share it. 
Kind regards - Igor

Comment: I think this belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TJ _"And it mostly works"_ is a smell that this question is probably off-topic for codereview. Besides, in cases the code actually works as intended and is posted on codereview, stub code like `set: function () {/*some code*/},` is also off-topic there.